# Laravel belongs to (more than 1 table)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-6

has a rookie in laravel i don't no very well where and how to do this.

I have 3 tables that have almost the same fields, but they all have in comon ID

```
public function book(){

     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\table1', 'book_id', 'id');
}
```

this works but can i do something like this??
What should i use?

```
 public function book(){

     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\table1','App\Models\table2', 'book_id', 'id');
}
```

Thanks for sharing your knowlege.

Answer (score 3):

You may define 2 separate belongsTo functions

```
//...
public function book(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Book', 'foreign_key', 'primary_key');
}

public function author(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Author', 'foreign_key', 'primary_key');
}
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't create a single relationship with two tables in that way, that's not the way Laravel reads the method.

It would be pretty easy, and likely most clear for code readability to just make two separate relationships:

```
public function book(){

  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\table1', 'foreign_key');
}

public function otherBook(){

 return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\table2', 'foreign_key');
}
```

But, it may be worth your time to consider the overall architecture of your models and tables first.  If these tables share a common ID, that's going to get quite confusing over time, and carry a lot of overhead to make sure you don't over-write.  Why not just make one table with some kind of flag to identify the different types of book?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks i have alot to leearn :D